# Avoid a GA fitness function with diverging goals getting stuck

Tags: genetic-algorithm

I'm working on a genetic algorithm as a sort of having-fun-with-programming exercise.

The problem is about mapping two texts in different languages one to another by sentences. Since different translations can start and end sentences in different places, there is a large, but not perfect correspondence between the texts.

So, take for example two strings:

```
a X. a a Y. a aaa a. X a a. a aa. aaa a Y aa.

X b bb. b Y bb bbb b X bb. bb. b. bb Y. bbb b.
```

where X and Y are anchors and As and Bs language specific words. The gene I'm working on takes all existing sentence breaks (full stops excluding the finishing ones) as binary values; the example above has six sentences in both texts, so ten bits are needed. Working manually, not understanding the text itself, I would assume the best answer is:

```
10011 11010
```

(1 - no change, 0 - dot removed and sentences merged) which would result in:

```
a X. a a Y a aaa a X a a. a aa. aaa a Y aa.

X b bb. b Y bb bbb b X bb. bb b. bb Y bbb b.
```

My fitness function evaluates four conditions, as follows:

1. The number of sentences should be as high as possible.
2. There must be an equal number of sentences in both texts.
3. The lengths of sentences should be as close as possible.
4. As many anchors as possible should be found in the same sentence in both texts (anchors are for example character names in a sample novel I'm using).

However, I'm not getting the result I'm hoping for since the condition 2, which is very important, takes over no matter what I do and evolution stops. If I don't heavily tweak what's happening, I end up either merging the whole thing into one huge sentence (gene 00000 00000 above) or finding the first matching number of sentences and getting stuck.

In general, how can this problem be overcome? How can I make my fitness function not stuck when a list of conditions that work against each other is needed? Should the process be divided into two stages? How can I then reintroduce condition 2 after some evolution? Should I evaluate it every N generations?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting the problem into two stages I think you'd be better to work on improving your fitness function. Having conditions that work against each other doesn't have to be a problem. The key is how your fitness score is calculated. If you give each condition a weight, each can be tweaked for better results.

If you could give more detail about the fitness score it might be easier to work out what is going on but it seems that certain conditions have an inherently greater weight than the others. Especially since condition 1 should give a low score if the result is one huge sentence, and vice versa. By tweaking the relative weights of each condition you should be able to aim for a gene where both conditions do well, rather than one or the other.